# Calculate loan payment with variable frequency

Tags: php, math, formula

Trying to build a loan payment calculator where the user can input a frequency, such as monthly, semi-monthly, bi-weekly, weekly. I got a formula working for monthly, but I'm having trouble converting it to the other frequencies. Does anyone have any ideas?

This is the formula I'm using:

```
function pmt($interest, $months, $loan) {
    $interest = $interest / 1200; 
    $amount = $interest * -$loan * pow((1 + $interest), $months) / (1 - pow((1 + $interest), $months));
    return number_format($amount, 2);
}
```

The following values seem to work for a monthly loan payment:

```
$interest = 5; 
$months = 24;
$loan = 20000;

echo pmt($interest, $months, $loan);
// 877.43
```

But how can I account for variable frequencies? Here was my best attempt at it, but the numbers seem to be off from other online calculators.

```
$weekly = 12/52;
$biWeekly = 12/26;
$semiMonthly = 12/24;
$monthly = 12/12;

$monthlyFrequency = $biWeekly;

$interest = 5; 
$months = 24 / $monthlyFrequency;
$loan = 20000;

echo pmt($interest, $months, $loan);
```

Comment: In your "best attempt" I don't actually see you calculating anything, just setting variables. What was the result? What would you expect the result to be?

Comment: @Mike Ah good catch, I've updated the question. I'm using the variables on the same function.

Comment: You still didn't say what your result was and what you would expect it to be. I think this is more of a math question instead of an actual programming question, so I've added the math tag. Once you figure out the actual formula and values you need to be using, I would imagine the programming should be relatively trivial.